# How can I check a for specific character as well as these lengths using regex

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression

^(?=[\s\S]*$)(?:.{10}|.{11})$

This will get a match as long as it is 10 or 11 characters, but how can I make it check for a specific character / as well? 
So it has to be 10 or 11 characters and contain a /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
^(?=.*\/).{10,11}$
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `(?=.*\/)` - Positive lookahead. condition for `/` must.
- `.{10,11}` - Match anything except new line 10 or 11 time.
- `$` - End of string.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/IWeLMi/1/)